# Filter based on the last two records

Tags: crystal-reports

My report needs to identify when an event has occurred in the last two records for a customer. I created a running total and used that to look at only the last records per customer. How can I show only records where *both* of the last two records have this event?

So if I have:

```
Customer 1 Record Meets Criteria  
Customer 1 Record Doesn't Meet Criteria  

Customer 2 Record Meets Criteria  
Customer 2 Record Meets Criteria  

Customer 3 Record Doesn't Meet Criteria  
Customer 3 Record Doesn't Meet Criteria
```

I should only see:

```
Customer 2 Record Meets Criteria  
Customer 2 Record Meets Criteria
```

---

I attempted to use this custom SQL command, but it only pulled a single record:

```
SELECT top(2) DateAdded
FROM customer_history.date_of_service
ORDER BY DateAdded DESC
```

Comment: You could probably pull this off in Crystal, but you'd have better luck setting this up with a SQL Command in the Database Expert.

Comment: I think part of the issue may be the tables themselves and the software program that is using crystal reports. It has a problem where it can only handle the simplest commands from sql